# calling an array defined in one method in another method

Tags: ruby

am learning ruby and i had come across this particular issue.

I have method which reads the user input data into an array and i have another method which displays the values in the same array to the user with some processing.

However this doesnt seem to be the correct way as the system always throws a 
**Arraypass.rb:23:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method`names' for main:Object (NameError)**

Appreciate if someone can show a way forward in this,

for example:

```
class School

   def askdetails
     print "How many students are there"
     n=(gets.chomp.to_i - 1)
     print "Enter names one by one"
     names=Array.new(n)
       for i in (0..n)
       names[i]=gets.chomp
       end
     return names,n
   end

   def showdetails(names,n)
     for i in (0..n)
     puts names[i]
     end
   end
end

stud=School.new
stud.askdetails
stud.showdetails(names,n)
```

Comment: Hi Arup, missed out the issue. it shows me an undefined variable issue. I have now pasted the exact error message

Comment: try: 
`name, n = stud.askdetails

stud.showdetails(names,n)`

Comment: `showdetails(names,n)` from here you are getting. `name` is not being created a `local var`. What is your goal ?

Comment: The goal is to use the same array in a different method and to see how it can be done. The code that you have suggested is working. Thank you very much Arup and GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the code as

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class School

  def askdetails
    print "How many students are there"
    n = gets.chomp.to_i - 1
    print "Enter names one by one"
    names = Array.new(n)
    for i in (0..n)
      names[i]=gets.chomp
    end
    return names,n
  end

  def showdetails(names,n)
    for i in (0..n)
      puts names[i]
    end
  end
end

stud = School.new
names, n = stud.askdetails
stud.showdetails(names,n)
```

The thing, you missed is `#askdetails` methods returning an `Array`, which you didn't assign any where before using those.

Read [Array Decomposition](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition), this is what I did here :

```
names, n = stud.askdetails
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer:

```
names,n = stud.askdetails  
stud.showdetails(names,n)
```

Comment: @anoop I think my comment and answer sorted out your problem. isn't it so ?

Comment: Hi G.B, yes ur answer did solve my problem, but i could accept only one answer. So to be fair, i accepted what came first. Please let me knw if i am wrong

Comment: Hi G.B, i tried doing that as well. But it doesnt allow me saying that upvote requires 15 reputation. currently i have only one. am sorry bro.